# Cassandra multi node balancing

Tags: cassandra

I have added a new node into the cluster and was expecting the data on Cassandra to balance itself across nodes. 
`node status` yields

```
$ nodetool status
Datacenter: dc1
===============
Status=Up/Down
|/ State=Normal/Leaving/Joining/Moving
--  Address      Load       Tokens       Owns (effective)  Host ID    Rack
UN  10.128.0.7   270.75 GiB  256          48.6%        1a3f6faa-4376-45a8-9c20-11480ae5664c  rack1
UN  10.128.0.14  414.36 KiB  256          51.4%        66a89fbf-08ba-4b5d-9f10-55d52a199b41  rack1
```

Load of node 2 is just 400KB, we have time series data and query on that. how can I rebalance the load between these clusters?
configuration for both nodes are

```
cluster_name: 'cluster1'
 - seeds: "node1_ip, node2_ip"
num_tokens: 256
endpoint_snitch: GossipingPropertyFileSnitch
auto_bootstrap: false
```

thank you for your time :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I have added a new node into the cluster and was expecting the data on Cassandra to balance itself across nodes.

Explicitly setting `auto_bootstrap: false' tells it *not* to do that.

> how can I rebalance the load?

1. Set your keyspace to a RF of 2.
2. Run `nodetool -h 10.128.0.14 repair`.

-Or-

1. Take the 10.128.0.14 out of the cluster.
2. Set `auto_bootstrap: true` (or just remove it).
3. And start the node up.  It should join and stream data.

Pro-tip: With a data footprint of 270GB, you should have been running with more than one node to begin with.  It would have been much easier to start with 3 nodes (which is probably the minimum you should be running on).

Comment: thanks aaron, I removed 10.128.0.14 and added a new node with bootstrap conf removed, it did join the cluster but result of node status is the same. few KB on new node. shouldn't owns percentage reflect the load?

Comment: @Junaid Ok, don't configure the new node as a seed node.  For seed nodes, only list 10.128.0.7.

Comment: Yes I did exactly that.